# C# MSAGL change icons

Tags: c#, winforms, toolbar, msagl

I build an winforms application in c#.

I'm trying to change the default icons of MSAGL `GViewer` component:

[image: MSAGL icons]

but I don't find where to do that.

How can I change them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GViewer` control uses an old [`ToolBar`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.toolbar(v=vs.110).aspx) control to show those buttons. To replace those icons, you can find the toolbar in controls collection of the viewer control and set a new [`ImageList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelist(v=vs.110).aspx) containing new images for the toolbar:

```
var toolbar = this.gViewer.Controls["toolbar"] as ToolBar;
toolbar.ImageList = this.imageList1;
```

The image list should have 18 images in below order. When adding images to image list. After adding images, set the `Name` property of image at index 2 to `zoom.bmp` because the toolbar use it's name instead of index:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Using above images, and `ColorDepth` set to `Depth24Bit` and `TransparentColor` set to `Magenta` here is the final result:

[image]

Also as another option you can set `ToolBarIsVisible` property of `GViewer` component to `false` and use your own `ToolStrip` or `ToolBar`. Then when clicking each button, you can call corresponding method of viewer component, like `ZoomInPressed`, `ZoomOutPressed`, `BackwardButtonPressed`, `ForwardButtonPressed`, ... .

**Note:**

For more information you can take a look at [Microsoft Automatic Graph Layout](https://github.com/Microsoft/automatic-graph-layout) source code repository and source code for [`GViewer`](https://github.com/Microsoft/automatic-graph-layout/blob/master/GraphLayout/tools/GraphViewerGDI/GViewer.cs) control.

Comment: The solution is completely tested and works properly. Do you have any problem applying the answer? Let me know if you have any question about answer or if you find it helpful. Waiting to hear from you :)

Comment: By some reason the icon on index 3 is not appear:

https://s32.postimg.org/8f3rtkpud/Capture.png

Comment: Probably you didn't see this part of the answer: *When adding images to image list, set the name of image at index 2 to zoom.bmp because the toolbar use it's name insetead of index*. After adding the images in the specified order, for image at index 2 of imagelist, set name to `zoom.bmp`.

Comment: Actually I saw that part this how my list look a like: https://s32.postimg.org/4ca0ehnb9/Captur2e.png

Comment: Let me check, maybe I wrote it wrong, the screenshot is taken from a working sample. I'll check it in a minute...

Comment: Everything is OK, so to make sure you are setting the value correctly, Open `Images` collection editor of `ImageList`, click on image at index 2, make sure in the propertygrid, in front of `Name` property the value is `zoom.bmp`

Comment: Yes it is like that: https://s32.postimg.org/lx6lqz96d/zoomislikethat.png

Comment: Oops, the mistake is here. You should change item at index 2. Indexes are zero based, you should change the name of item at index not 0, not 1, but **2**, in fact 3rd item.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116607/discussion-between-cuzi-and-reza-aghaei).